# Expected value and variance

Tags: statistics

If the life length of a certain kind of light bulb (in years) is a random variable given by the density $f(x) = (10-x)/50$,  $ 0\le x\le 10$, f(x) = 0 otherwise. Suppose a bulb has already been used for 5 years. Let T be the life length of this light bulb. What's E(T) and V(T)?

I'm confused about this problem, is it correct to say that E(T) is the same as E(X|X=5)?

Comment: If really your exercise is phrased like that (considering a non existent T), you might want to knock the author on the head. Indeed the question they mean to ask is what are E(X|X>5) and V(X|X>5) if X has PDF f. Can you solve it?

Comment: I tried solving for E(X|X>5), would I be using the density f(x|x>5)? If that's the density, it becomes 1?

Comment: ?? Why not compute E(X;A) and P(A) for A=[X>5], and deduce E(X|A)=E(X;A)/P(A)?

Comment: hmm, computed to be 20/3 actually